# How can I filter the counter less than a parameter in Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, grouping, kibana

I have a question similar to this: How can I filter a field **greater** than a counter on Kibana? https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/9684

On this link there is a perfect answer: You need use "{'min_doc_count': X}" on your Json Input Advanced Bucket Option. Perfect, It runs exactly like I want, except because I want the oposite, something like "max_doc_count".

For my surprise, this options doesn't existis... Some one knows what would be the "max_doc_count" equivalent of?

In SQL would be something like: GROUP BY my_field HAVING COUNT(*) < 3

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The correct way of doing this in ES is to use a [`bucket_selector` pipeline aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html) with the [special `_count` path](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline.html#_special_paths).

```
POST /_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "my_terms": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "my_field.keyword"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "max_doc_count": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "count": "_count"
            },
            "script": {
              "source": "params.count < 3"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the results, the `my_terms` aggregations will only contain buckets where the document count is < 3. No need to order anything or to program your application to ignore anything.

Comment: Ok, this is a great query, but it runs only on kibana's console. I need create a graph with this result, that's why I refer something like "{'min_doc_count': X}", that code can be used on advanced JSON option.

Comment: You might be able to achieve something similar with the Visual Builder visualization.

Comment: I took a look at "Visual Builder Visualization" but I didn't really find what I needed. Could you be more specific, please? Note: the version of my Kibana is: 6.1.3

Comment: In the some visualizations (Top N, Metric, etc), in the Panel Options, you have a setting at the bottom that reads "Set bar to [color] if metric is [greater, less than] some value". That's something you can configure to your liking. However, I'm not sure how your graph should look like, so I can't provide a sample.

Comment: OK, my idea is create a table where rows has the records ids with "counter = 1"(or counter < 2) grouped by a key. The grouping that has 2 or more records don't interest me.

Comment: There's an issue that is still open in Kibana to leverage the `bucket_selector` pipeline aggregation in visualizations: https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/17544