# Filter on the aggregation doc_count in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am working on elasticsearch and trying to filter the aggregated data depending on the doc_count. There is min_doc_count with which I can mention the minimum doc_count. But what if I want to find the aggregated results where doc_count is equal to or less than a given number? Is there any solution on how to solve this?

```
GET interaction-v2/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_user": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "customer_id",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51623147/how-can-i-filter-the-counter-less-than-a-parameter-in-kibana/51833731#51833731

Comment: You can find a solution here https://discuss.elastic.co/t/filter-based-on-the-doc-count-with-aggregations/62677/2

Comment: Thank you both for your help, I already tried the @Pierre Mallet link, but it didn't work because at the "source" only "the_doc_count" wouldn't work and needed to be written as "params.the_doc_count"!

Answer (score 0):

Answer is here: [Elasticsearch filter aggregations on minimal doc count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29843712/elasticsearch-filter-aggregations-on-minimal-doc-count)

To save you looking it up:

```
aggs: {
    field1: {
        terms: {
            field: 'field1',
            min_doc_count: 1000
        },
```